# (Exchange 2003) Outlook Web Access and firefox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, firefox

We are evaluating to switch our mailenable mail server to an exchange 2003 one.
The web interface of mailenable is great, and works fine with firefox.
I am wondering if outlook web access (exchange 2003) can be configured to work with firefox in premium mode (as everyone in the company is urged to use firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with Exchange 2003.  The Premium client will be accessible via Firefox in the Exchange 14 release.  More details:

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/02/12/450639.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is anecdotal but I'm using firefox on Fedora to access OWA (2k3 Exchange server) and it works flawlessly.  On my XP virtual machine it works fine in firefox as well.  On the other hand, getting a linux mail client to talk to exchange is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

We have Exchange 2003 server and run webmail, routing through an ISA proxy server for external access.  I would **not** do the ISA proxy again, it has been troublesome.  I would likely do an Exchange gateway instead.

I disagree with [kentchen](https://serverfault.com/questions/21972/exchange-2003-outlook-web-access-and-firefox/21992#21992) about OWA in Firefox; it is a good solution.  It isn't as pretty as OWA in IE, and there isn't drag and drop to folders, but it is **really** fast.  Unless they are using Outlook now, you won't hear complaints. The IETab add-on is a reasonable option, as long as the users are discouraged from using it for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can have them use IE8 instead, you should also consider going to exchange 2007 for a better OWA experience

Answer (score 0):

It would be better using IE TAb add-on in Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419). It basically uses IE engine inside the Firefox. I have been using it for years and found it very useful. It has become one of the must-have add-ins in my Firefox.

Don't have the experience for Exchange 2007, but until 2003, OWA is best used in IE, not other browsers.